# Generic Import Table AA - ZZ Creation

Tags: sql, oracle

I require a generic style import table.  Data used in each column is likely to be added/changed in the future.  So I'd like to create a wide table and just document what each column represents and than query the table through a view where I can provide meaningful column names.

Aside from pasting 600+ columns, is there a way to script creating this type of table?  Perhaps also there is a feature better used than this type of approach.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a PL/SQL script that does built the create table string and then executes it with an execute immediate statement. Are you sure the database design is correct? 600 columns sounds like the normalization has not been done.

```
declare
    l_sql     varchar2(32000);
begin
     l_sql := 'create table mytable (';
     for i in 1 .. 600 loop
           l_sql := l_sql || ' col'||i||' char(10)';
           if i<600 then
              l_sql := l_sql || ',';
           end if;
     end loop;
     l_sql := l_sql || ')';
     execute immediate l_sql;
end;
/
```

Comment: It's intentional.  Typical Star Schema.  Normalization is overrated ;)